# Search all objects in array and return match

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to look thought my array and find the object where the field `"Primary": true`

But i'm kinda stuck on how to make the return status so it return the correct value.

In my head it would be `return element.Country.Primary == true` But `Country` is a dynamic value so it can be anything.

Is there a way i can get the data i want.

The result I'm looking for is the entire "Country" object

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.cDropdown = function(x) {

    return this.each(function() {

      var wrapper = $(this);
      var xx = $.extend({
        obj: "",
      }, x || {});

      function initialized() {
        console.clear();
        var returnedData = $.grep(xx.obj, function(element, index) {
          //return element where "Primary" == true
        });

      }

      function initFirst(obj) {

      }

      initialized();
    });
  };

}(jQuery));

$('#cDropdown').cDropdown({
  obj: [{
    "Country": {
      "Id": "Country",
      "Name": "Country",
      "Primary": true,
      "Child": "City",
      "option": [{
        "val": "DK",
        "text": "Denmark"
      }, {
        "val": "ENG",
        "text": "England"
      }]
    },
    "City": {
      "Id": "City",
      "Name": "City",
      "Primary": false,
      "option": [{
        "val": "Aal",
        "text": "Aalborg",
        "trigger": "DK"
      }, {
        "val": "Lon",
        "text": "London",
        "trigger": "DK"
      }]
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cDropdown"></select>
```

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/aghosh08/Leexewt4/

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I need to get the object of my array That contains "Primary": true, Since Country can be anything it has to be dynamic